# How are false positives possible? Since shouldn't mathematical methods be "exact"?

Tags: error, false-positive-rate

That is, it's not possible to have true as false, but isn't that basically what a false positive or a false negative does? That it gives a prediction of a condition existing, when it does not?

So how is this possible?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation)

Comment: 1. I roll a six-sided die but don't how you which face landed uppermost. The die is symmetric and I rolled it a long way.  I ask you to predict the face that's uppermost. You can use mathematical methods ... so you should get the right answer every time, right? (How could you possibly get it wrong? Shouldn't mathematical methods be exact?)  $\:$  2. Let's predict next years weather (say the maximum temperature and rainfall for every day of 2019) using mathematical methods. How can we ever get it wrong? Shouldn't mathematical methods be exact?

Answer (score 2):

False positives and false negatives arise in the context of binary decision problems in statistics, where you have an underlying unknown binary state, and you use data to predict that unknown state.  A "false positive" means that you have predicted that a particular "positive" state is true, but it turns out you are wrong.  In deductive mathematical problems outside of statistics, the observed information may be sufficient to logically imply the true underlying state, in which case it should be possible (in theory at least) to predict this state exactly.  Statistical problems arise when the data is insufficiently informative to logically imply the true underlying state of nature, and so we make inferences using probability theory and statistical methods, and our predictions are inexact - they have some chance of being wrong.

Perhaps a useful re-framing of your question is: What is the mathematical/statistical procedure that is able to predict unknown states of nature exactly, from limited statistical data, without any false positives.  If you are aware of such a procedure, it will be of great interest to people, and you should feel free to share it with us.  If you are unable to find or create such a procedure, then I think that gives you your answer.